# Woocommerce cart items keep reappearing

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

i made a video of the woocommerce cart issue a friend of mine has with his store https://streamable.com/augha

i cannot reproduce it here, on other pc's. Nor can i reproduce it on my mobile phone.

This was yesterday... But now today the problem seems to be expanding to the moment it seems that customers from belgium are also getting this problem. In the past we have never had problems with Belgium, and yesterday we also received a Belgian order with several articles without any problems.
But another order we have to make a payment link because he did not manage to get more than 4 items in the basket.

The remarkable thing I find that the Belgian where we made a payment link initially got 15 hoodies in his shopping basket, and the next day the basket was empty and he could add up to 4.

So it seems that in certain occasions the cart will go fubar... Anyone else experienced this ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a caching issue. You may want to try disabling all other plugins to see if that helps.

Comment: Thats what i thought too... But there is no plugin that does something with a cache what so ever. :-(